# C# negative value with Linq according to output from the database

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

I have a database called **Objects**.

Then I've created a simple gridView that contains a list from my db **Objects** table, the list shows data according to an enum class called **Type**. So in short the list will only show data of Type **Negative and Positive**

**In my gridView there is a column called Quantity.**

*This is how I coded it:*

```
 var objects= db.Objects.Where(x =>
                x.Type == ClassType.Positive || x.Type == Class.Negative).Select(so=> so).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable().ToList();
```

### Now to the problem & question...

Everything works almost perfectly, by that I mean the program does almost what it must.

What I want to do and cannot do is this: everytime the enum value Negative shows up I want the Quantity (which is some number, for example 23 or 43) to be - and by that I mean the number and then the "-" symbol. So lets say that The enum value Negative shows up, then I would like the number to be -23. Hope I am clear.

I am not quite sure how this problem can be solved, maybe with Linq?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please don't use so much of bold and large case. Quotation marks is ok for highlighting certain specific values

Comment: Use a view class in which a display property for Quantity is composed. Side note: you could find a more meaningful name than "objects".

Comment: @GertArnold the real name is not Objects, I just did not wanted to give the real name of my db :) but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

Here is how:

```
Type == ClassType.IntermediateNegative ? (-f.so.Quantity) : (f.so.Quantity)
```

So what it does is

1. it looks if the Type == ClassType.IntermediateNegative
2. if the statement is true, it then sets a minus in front of the integer
3. then again if the statement is false, it shows the number without minus.